# Error when removing a TitleWindow via PopUpManager

Tags: flex4.5, popupwindow

I am having issues to remove a PopUp form my application. In fact I have a title Window with a component in it. In the component I have a Button, which when clicked should remove the TitleWindow (the PopUp). I am getting the error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

My Title Window is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" left="10"
               width="1366" height="768">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

    public function removeTitleWindow():void {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="left">
        <comps:SearchEngine />
        <comps:SearchResults />
    </s:VGroup>

</s:TitleWindow>






My Component is as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400 " height="300">

<fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


            <s:Button label="Cancel" click="parentApplication.parentApplication.removeTitleWindow()"/>

    </s:VGroup>

</s:Group>
```

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Mates :)

I tried using parentApplication or rather flexGlobals.top... It didnt work.

Hence I used parentDocument.methodName().

This solved the issue.